# Python3 - replace string require if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I just want to replace `'dog'` with anything!

Think I need an if statement but can't get one that makes sense:

```
wordlist = ['cat','dog','rabbit','test',]

letterlist = []
for aword in wordlist:
    aword.replace('dog', 'OMG IT WORKED? OR NOT')
    print (aword)
    letterlist.append(aword)

print(letterlist)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.replace()` *returns a new string*; you want to rebind `aword` to it:

```
aword = aword.replace('dog', 'OMG IT WORKED? OR NOT')
```

`str` is an immutable type; you can only produce a new value with changes, not change the value itself.

Comment: Dammit Martjin, that was finally one I could answer.  You're too fast for life.